# Bind XML to Kendo Treeview

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

How can I bind this XML to Kendo TreeView

```
<ParentNode text="Main Node">
    <DirectChilds>
        <DirectChild childof="MainNode" childpath="5371,3255" childs="1377667720378,1377667721403,1377667722362" id="1377667719986" left="5381px" pathid="CHILD_1377667719986" text="hi" top="3235px"/>
        <DirectChild childof="MainNode" childpath="5894,3310" childs="1377667730535,1377667731738,1377667733020" id="1377667729193" left="5848px" pathid="CHILD_1377667729193" text="hi" top="3290px"/>
        <DirectChild childof="MainNode" childpath="5749,3483" childs="1377667736891,1377667738258" id="1377667735482" left="5703px" pathid="CHILD_1377667735482" text="hi" top="3463px"/>
    </DirectChilds>-
    <DirectPaths>
        <DirectPath d="M5680,3337.5Q5539.5,3196.25,5399,3255" id="CHILD_1377667719986"/>
        <DirectPath d="M5680,3337.5Q5773,3223.75,5866,3310" id="CHILD_1377667729193"/>
        <DirectPath d="M5680,3337.5Q5700.5,3510.25,5721,3483" id="CHILD_1377667735482"/></DirectPaths>-
    <SubChilds>
        <SubChild childof="1377667719986" childpath="" childs="" id="1377667720378" left="5245px" pathid="CHILD_1377667720378" text="hi" top="3235px"/>
        <SubChild childof="1377667719986" childpath="5235,3295" childs="1377667723338,1377667725497,1377667726857" id="1377667721403" left="5245px" pathid="CHILD_1377667721403" text="hi" top="3275px"/>
        <SubChild childof="1377667719986" childpath="" childs="" id="1377667722362" left="5245px" pathid="CHILD_1377667722362" text="hi" top="3195px"/>
        <SubChild childof="1377667721403" childpath="" childs="" id="1377667723338" left="5109px" pathid="CHILD_1377667723338" text="hi" top="3275px"/>
        <SubChild childof="1377667721403" childpath="" childs="" id="1377667725497" left="5109px" pathid="CHILD_1377667725497" text="hi" top="3315px"/>
        <SubChild childof="1377667721403" childpath="" childs="" id="1377667726857" left="5109px" pathid="CHILD_1377667726857" text="hi" top="3235px"/>
        <SubChild childof="1377667729193" childpath="" childs="" id="1377667730535" left="5984px" pathid="CHILD_1377667730535" text="hi" top="3290px"/>
        <SubChild childof="1377667729193" childpath="6030,3350" childs="1377667734301" id="1377667731738" left="5984px" pathid="CHILD_1377667731738" text="hi" top="3330px"/>
        <SubChild childof="1377667729193" childpath="" childs="" id="1377667733020" left="5984px" pathid="CHILD_1377667733020" text="hi" top="3250px"/>
        <SubChild childof="1377667731738" childpath="" childs="" id="1377667734301" left="6120px" pathid="CHILD_1377667734301" text="hi" top="3330px"/>
        <SubChild childof="1377667735482" childpath="" childs="" id="1377667736891" left="5839px" pathid="CHILD_1377667736891" text="hi" top="3463px"/>
        <SubChild childof="1377667735482" childpath="5885,3523" childs="1377667739865,1377667742753" id="1377667738258" left="5839px" pathid="CHILD_1377667738258" text="hi" top="3503px"/>
        <SubChild childof="1377667738258" childpath="" childs="" id="1377667739865" left="5975px" pathid="CHILD_1377667739865" text="hi" top="3503px"/>
        <SubChild childof="1377667738258" childpath="6021,3563" childs="1377667744827" id="1377667742753" left="5975px" pathid="CHILD_1377667742753" text="hi" top="3543px"/>
        <SubChild childof="1377667742753" childpath="" childs="" id="1377667744827" left="6111px" pathid="CHILD_1377667744827" text="hi" top="3543px"/></SubChilds>-
    <SubChildPaths>
        <SubChildPath d="M5399,3255L5371,3255M5371,3255Q5371,3255,5263,3255M5371,3255Q5371,3315,5263,3295M5371,3255Q5371,3195,5263,3215" id="ChildContainer_1377667719986"/>
        <SubChildPath d="M5263,3295L5235,3295M5235,3295Q5235,3295,5127,3295M5235,3295Q5235,3355,5127,3335M5235,3295Q5235,3235,5127,3255" id="ChildContainer_1377667721403"/>
        <SubChildPath d="M5884,3310L5894,3310M5894,3310Q5894,3310,6002,3310M5894,3310Q5894,3370,6002,3350M5894,3310Q5894,3250,6002,3270" id="ChildContainer_1377667729193"/>
        <SubChildPath d="M6020,3350L6030,3350M6030,3350Q6030,3350,6138,3350" id="ChildContainer_1377667731738"/>
        <SubChildPath d="M5739,3483L5749,3483M5749,3483Q5749,3483,5857,3483M5749,3483Q5749,3543,5857,3523" id="ChildContainer_1377667735482"/>
        <SubChildPath d="M5875,3523L5885,3523M5885,3523Q5885,3523,5993,3523M5885,3523Q5885,3583,5993,3563" id="ChildContainer_1377667738258"/>
        <SubChildPath d="M6011,3563L6021,3563M6021,3563Q6021,3563,6129,3563" id="ChildContainer_1377667742753"/></SubChildPaths>-
    <Openers>
        <Opener for="1377667719986" left="5363px" src="/Images/close.png" top="3247px"/>
        <Opener for="1377667721403" left="5227px" src="/Images/close.png" top="3287px"/>
        <Opener for="1377667729193" left="5886px" src="/Images/close.png" top="3302px"/>
        <Opener for="1377667731738" left="6022px" src="/Images/close.png" top="3342px"/>
        <Opener for="1377667735482" left="5741px" src="/Images/close.png" top="3475px"/>
        <Opener for="1377667738258" left="5877px" src="/Images/close.png" top="3515px"/>
        <Opener for="1377667742753" left="6013px" src="/Images/close.png" top="3555px"/></Openers>
</ParentNode>
```

Comment: Have you read Kendo docs and [demos](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datasource/xml-data.html)? I am not sure whether you can do that though. JSON is a good option.

Comment: Yes I have read but dint find the way.. I am a beginner in this actually so its a bit confusing.